Retrace dataloss
I'm working on a project about finding dataloss on android app. My problem is that once i'm done testing an app using a dataloss detection tool, i get a list of dataloss but since i'm new to android app and and everything that concerns it, i don't know how to retrace that dataloss so i can manually replicate it. For example given this dataloss: [{"text":"abc","clazz":"android.widget.EditText","resource_id":"com.beemdevelopment.aegis:id/text_password"}]
I don't know how to get to the right options to interact with, in this case "text_password" i guess . How can i find it?  I'm hope i expressed myself well, for anything feel free to ask. Thanks
I've come to reach the right activity (PreferencesActivity) in the app, using: adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'". Now once i'm here, it's full of other option to interact with and don't know what to do.

You should share more info - such as name of the data loss tool. What that tool helps you to find. What are you tryingto fix, etc.

Yes sure, i'm actually using "iFixDataloss" as data loss detection tool, it helps me find datalosses such as for example if i insert a text in a text box and then i do a double rotation the text resets. My job is once the test ends, i need to retrace the dataloss so i can manually test it on the app

do you have the app's source code? Do you know Android development? I would just use search function to find view with text_password id, and do appropriate changes to it.

Yes i do have source code but i'm kinda new to android development. So i could use search function on the app on android studio?
